Nextjs 14 set cookie not working in route handler
In the route handler, the cookie value is returned correctly, but in the server component, the cookie value is undefined.
/api/oauth/route.ts
export const POST = async (req: Request) => {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const { code, provider } = await req.json();
  console.log(req, code, provider);
  const redirectUri =
    provider === "google"
      ? `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE}/oauth?provider=google`
      : "/";

  const { data } = await server.post(`auth/${provider}/token`, {
    authorizationCode: code,
    redirectUri: redirectUri,
  });

  const { refreshToken, accessToken } = data;

  cookieStore.set("accessToken", accessToken, {
    path: "/",
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
  });

  const response = NextResponse.json(
    { success: true },
    {
      status: 200,
      statusText: "Set Cookie Successfully",
    },
  );

  response.cookies.set("accessToken", accessToken, {
    path: "/",
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
  });

  console.log("Access Token Set: ", cookieStore.get("accessToken")?.value);

  return response;
};


page.tsx
interface IOAuth {
  searchParams: {
    code: string;
    provider: string;
  };
}
const OAuthPage = async ({ searchParams }: IOAuth) => {
  const res = await axios.post(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE}/api/oauth`,
    searchParams,
    { withCredentials: true },
  );

  const accessToken = cookies().get("accessToken")?.value;
  console.log(accessToken); // undefined
  return permanentRedirect("/");
};

export default OAuthPage;


I’ve tried several methods to set the cookie, but the cookie value is only available in route.ts, while it's undefined elsewhere. I tested it in the server component, but it also returns undefined in the middleware where I want to use the cookie.
